# need assistance understanding objective-c blocks

Tags: ios

This is from [apple blocks docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW3) and I am having difficulty understanding this please can any one explain in little easy way

> ...You can cast a block reference to a pointer of arbitrary type and
>   vice versa. You cannot, however, dereference a block reference via the
>   pointer dereference operator (*)—thus a block's size cannot be
>   computed at compile time.

Comment: [This](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/ugly-side-of-blocks-explicit.html?m=1) should answer your questions, and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put simply, a block is a reference. The code within the block is stored in memory, and can be accessed via a variable. `void (^addingBlock)(int);` is a block declaration, that can be accessed via the addingBlock variable (as in, it can be called like `addingBlock(5);`).

Now, this reference can be transformed into a pointer type, that C recognises. Sort of like a function pointer. As the documentation states, the only visual difference is the use of `*` instead of `^`. This means you can cast a block to a function pointer:

```
void (*funcPointer)(int) = (void(*)(int))addingBlock;
```

Or even a void pointer (or any type!)

```
void* voidPtr = (void*)addingBlock;
```

But what the quote you're providing says, is that with this pointer to a block, you can't 'dereference' it. This means to interpret the pointer address, and get the data behind that address. Being unable to do this means you can't determine its size at compile time.

Why? Because of Obj-C's dynamic'ness; the contents of the block can only be determined at run time, whereas C is fairly static in nature, and determines a lot at compile time.